# Exclude all sub-directory's file using find

Tags: bash, unix

I have directory structure like this

```
data
|___
    |
    abc
     |____file0.jpg
     |____file1.jpg
     |____file2.jpg
    def
     |____file0.jpg
     |____file1.jpg
     |____file2.jpg
    ghi
     |____file0.jpg
     |____file1.jpg
     |____file2.jpg
    jkl
     |____file0.jpg
     |____file1.jpg
     |____file2.jpg
```

There is an `file0,file1,file2,` in all of the folders inside data directory. I try and success to make combine into `pdf` file of all directory. But I wish to ignore `file0` from all sub-directoy then combine as `pdf`. In a word i wish to merge `file1,file2` into pdf.

Here is My command:

```
for dir in data/*; do 
  cd "$dir"
  find . -type f -name \*0.jpg -not -path | convert ./*.jpg "$(basename "$dir")".pdf
  cd - 
done
```

Comment: No need for `find`. You are already in directory with both .jpg. First file is always *1.jpg and second *2.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need `find` for this, just a glob that excludes `file0.jpg`. This should work:

```
for dir in data/*; do
    (
    cd -- "$dir" || continue
    convert file[!0].jpg "$(basename "$dir")".pdf
    )
done
```

Here I've also added some guards on `cd` like the subshell to avoid cding out.

Comment: @nurislam You could test it easily just by putting an `echo` before `convert`, that way you can check that the command is correct. Welcome!

Comment: But one thing, the problem is that when some sub-folder contained with 10 files, some sub-folder contained with 4 files then, the code  may be complex..  if I ignore file0.jpg then may be easy to implement

Comment: @nurislam Ah, then use a glob that excludes file0 instead of including file{1,2}. I updated the answer.

Comment: Dear @wjandrea, I am new in Ubuntu, Even I know little bit. My last question is if i want to ignore file0 and file1, then? If u have a time pls ans. me in comment. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

For "find" try:

```
find . -type f -name "*[!0].jpg"
```

Comment: It's safer to quote the whole `-name` argument, like `"*[!0].jpg"`. Without quotes, it could be interpreted as a glob, which could theoretically expand to `*a.jpg *b.jpg`, which would cause `find` to fail.